# Clean architecture when developing SDKs

Tags: android, kotlin, architecture, sdk, clean-architecture

I'm developing an SDK with Kotlin (I intend to use the multiplatform function). This product will be integrated into the application through a dependency (like any current library).

The point is that I can't find information that explains how to structure this kind of projects. I would like to know if there are architectures similar to clean architecture for applications, but focused on these other needs.

The SDK contains a view (that the user can instantiate externally), internal logic and calls to a server. Does anyone who has faced this problem have any information?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are no guidelines such as "clean architecture" for libraries. Only the basic rule of thumb: make your library expose clean simple functions for your users.

Internally in your library, you can use all benefits from clean arch - let your `view` hold a `view-model`, propagate data using `live-data`, store to persistent using `room` e.t.c

Comment: @Re'em but isn't there a predefined pattern to follow? It's true that I can apply good practices as I see fit but I would like to find some structure to follow at a general level, although as you say probably does not exist.